# Dynamic Update ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am doing the dynamic ExpandableListView with a xml file, but I crashed when I load into the layout with no content in the list. Following is my code:

PasswordListingActivity.java:

```
public class PasswordListingActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {
    Button b_addPwd;
    ExpandableListView elv_pwdList;

    List<Map<String, String>> ServiceList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    List<List<Map<String, String>>> DetailList = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();

    ExpandableListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.passwordlisting);        

        b_addPwd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_addpwd);
        elv_pwdList = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.password_list);

        b_addPwd.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(PasswordListingActivity.this, AddPasswordActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }           
    });

    adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this, 
            ServiceList, 
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, 
            new String[] {"SERVICE"}, 
            null, 
            DetailList, 
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, 
            new String[] {"TITLE", "CONTENT",}, 
            null
    );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    switch (resultCode){
        case RESULT_OK:
            Bundle bundleR = data.getExtras();
            Map<String, String> ServiceGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            ServiceGroupMap.put("SERVICE", bundleR.getString("service"));
            ServiceList.add(ServiceGroupMap);
            List<Map<String, String>> DetailGroup = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            Map<String, String> DetailGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            DetailGroupMap.put("TITLE", "User Name: ");
            DetailGroupMap.put("CONTENT", bundleR.getString("username"));
            DetailGroup.add(DetailGroupMap);
            DetailGroupMap.put("TITLE", "Password: ");
            DetailGroupMap.put("CONTENT", bundleR.getString("password"));
            DetailGroup.add(DetailGroupMap);
            DetailList.add(DetailGroup);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

passwordlisting.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/password_listing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_add_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add" />
<ExpandableListView 
    android:id="@+id/password_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Error Code:

```
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

What is the problem of the code?

Comment: Find the section in the stack trace that points to one of your .java files. post that one and everything immediately around it. If none of the lines have one of your .java files try cleaning your project. And make sure all of the strigns referenced in your layout xml exist.

Comment: Just forgot to add PasswordListingActivity into AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID of the button in your xml layout does not match the ID you are passing to `findViewById();`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_add_list"
    ....
```

and

```
b_addPwd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_addpwd);
```

the part after "R.id." should match the part after "@+id/" What is happening is that you are getting null back from `findViewById();` because there is no View found with the id `R.id.b_addpwd`. Then when you try to call `.setOnClickListener()` it is likely throwing a NullPointer exception.

Comment: I didn't click on the button when it crashed. It crashed when it load the layout of passwordlisting.xml.